# SQL: Join value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table called `accounts` and another one called `level_points`

Basically the idea is to determine what is the minimum amount of points you need to be X level.

Account Structure

`id`, `name`.. etc. `points`

Level_Points Structure

`level`, `points`

Values in here such as

```
(1, 5)
(2, 10)
(3, 15)
```

I'm able to calculate the level using this query

```
SELECT `level` 
FROM `level_points` 
WHERE `points` <= (SELECT `points` 
                   FROM `accounts` 
                   WHERE `id` = 'x') 
ORDER BY `level` 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

My problem is that now i'm trying to join the tables to get something like this (For every user in the accounts table)

Result:

```
For user 1: `id`, `name` etc... `points`, `level`
For user 2: `id`, `name` etc... `points`, `level`
For user 3: `id`, `name` etc... `points`, `level`
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this using joins and I can't seem to find an answer here that helps me here.

Comment: Do you want the number of more points needed to make the next level for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ac.id,
    ac.name,
    ac.points,
    le.level
FROM account ac,
    level le
WHERE ac.id = 'x'
    AND le.level= (
        SELECT level
        FROM level_points
        WHERE points <= (
                SELECT points
                FROM accounts
                WHERE id = 'x'
                )
        ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1
        );
```

To get it for all players you can do:

```
SELECT ac.id,
    ac.name,
    ac.points,
    le.level
FROM accounts ac,
    level_points le
WHERE le.level= (
        SELECT level
        FROM level_points
        WHERE points <= (
                SELECT points
                FROM accounts ac2
                WHERE ac2.id = ac.id
                )
        ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1
        );
```

Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf8d2/1) to see it working

Comment: This works if im trying to get 1 row but since i'm trying to get it for every user the subquery returns more than 1 row =/

Comment: on the last query? That's impossible. See the link i have in my code. Are you sure you're not restricting it somewhere?

Comment: For some reason it wasn't returning all my values with <= but i changed <= to >= and desc to asc and it worked :O

Comment: That doesn't seem the problem. The query is ok. Do you have players that have less than the points for level 1? Try adding (0,0) to the level_points table. and Do my query again

Answer (score 0):

Try This ..

```
       select column1 from table1 
       inner join table2 on table1.column = table2.column
       where table2.column=0
```

Have a look at this

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would change `Level_Points` table thus:

```
ALTER TABLE Level_Points
ADD max_points INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE Level_Points
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LevelPoints_VerifyPoints CHECK(points < max_points);
```

In this cases, `points` column will store the minimum num. of points and `max_points` columns will store the maximum num. of points required for current level. Next, I have to be sure that this level are continuous, they aren't overlapping and there is no gaps (but these restrictions are beyond the purpose of this answer: see [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx) wrote by Alexander Kuznetsov). Also, some indexes are needed:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_LevelPoints_points
ON Level_Points(points);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_LevelPoints_points_maxpoints
ON Level_Points(points, max_points); -- This index is useful because the final query needs both columns: points and max_points; in SQL Server, max_points column can be covered column: ... ON Level_Points(points) INCLUDE (max_points), then the first index (IUN_LevelPoints_points) is no more needed
```

Some sample rows stored into this table:

```
INSERT INTO Level_Points ("level", "points", "max_points") VALUES (0, 0,  5); -- level 0 for players which have less than 5 points
INSERT INTO Level_Points ("level", "points", "max_points") VALUES (1, 5,  10);
INSERT INTO Level_Points ("level", "points", "max_points") VALUES (2, 10, 15);
INSERT INTO Level_Points ("level", "points", "max_points") VALUES (3, 15, 100);
INSERT INTO Level_Points ("level", "points", "max_points") VALUES (4, 100,2147483647); -- 2147483647 is the maximum value for a INT in SQL Server
```

In this cases, the final query is just a simple left/inner join:

```
SELECT ..., lvl.level
FROM accounts AS acc LEFT JOIN Level_Points AS lvl 
ON acc.points >= lvl.points 
AND acc.points < lvl.max_points
```